# How can I block certain keys in C++ with NCurses

Tags: c++, c, input, ncurses, curses

I'm new to C/C++ and I'm making a simple text user interface with `NCurses`.

Whenever I scroll up/down with the mouse wheel, or press arrow keys, the console echos characters like:

```
"[[A^[[C^[[B^[[D"
```

to show me that I've pressed the keys.

I would like to stop these from echoing and only echo basic keys (punctuation and letters).

Here is my main loop. I basically want it to be my own console with commands that I create.

```
string input;
char inputArr[80];
while (input != "q" && input != "quit" && input != "exit" && input != "leave") {
    printw(" > ");
    refresh();
    getstr(inputArr);
    input = inputArr;
    if (input.substr(0, 3) != "someCommand") {
        printw("\n ~ %s\n\n", inputArr);
        refresh();
    } else
        execCmd();
}
quit();
```

For the most part I believe it is C++ but I do have a C function (that uses libCurl).

Also, is there no cleaner way to read in strings with NCurses? I dont really like using char arrays (I'm used to Java).

Comment: Please show your code. Also, pick up a language you are using, too. C and C++ are different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `noecho()` somewhere close to `initscr()`.

This will avoid clobbering your screen with unwanted input. If you want your users to see what they type later on, you will need to call `echo()` before, however.

Comment: I want to echo letters and punctuation in the loop. I don't want to echo keys like arrows/mouse wheel. If I did noecho() then ALL input would be blocked. I only want this SPECIFIC input to be blocked (or have certain keys white-listed).

Comment: This is how it works: disable "automatic" output with `noecho()`and later on print everything you want to have printed explicitly yourself (with e.g. `printw()`).

Comment: I suppose. But then I would have to read in each character with getch() as the user is typing and see if it should be printed or not.